# R - get superfast list of files

Tags: r

on my folder I have around 500k files. I don't need to load it to R, but I need to load all filenames - that filenames will be used in code like this

```
files_on_disk <- "?"

result <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 4, 5)
  ) %>%
  filter(id %>% files_on_disk == F)
```

Since I have so many files I need some fast method that will be able to get just filenames, store it in list.

Comment: Maybe `list.files()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `list.files`

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```